# How to list customised flask commands

Tags: python, flask

I have a python flask app, and create some customised commands. But how do I list those commands in console?

Whenever I do `flask --help` it gives the default flask help message with only below two options:

- flask run
- flask shell

**update**

Actually if everything goes well, by default `flask --help` will list customised flask commands. The reason customised commands are not listed here is that my app is not imported properly due to some error.

By right, the error message should be printed out. But in my case, due to some weird config from 3rd party package there is no error message at all.

After I identified the 3rd party package, and commented it, my customised commands are listed properly.

Comment: Did you remember to set the FLASK_APP environment variable? When I do that and run 'flask' or 'flask --help' it lists all the commands decorated with `@app.cli.command()`

Comment: @MattHealy Thanks for your comment. yes, I do. I exported FLASK_APP to the module where I created "app". The only thing is I am using create_app() method to create app, not sure if it affects any thing.

Answer (score 1):

Check this from @miguelgrinberg [microblog - app/cli.py](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/blob/master/app/cli.py)

You need to register your group and then decorate your commands with your group :

```
@app.cli.group()
def group_name():
    pass

@group_name.command()
@click.argument('function_1')
def function_1():
    # Your function

...
```